# UserForm stays present over all workbooks. How can I stop this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have read some similar threads but am drawing a blank.
I have 2 workbooks open and when i click to a workbook other than the one that opens the UserForm, the UserForm remains.

I have this code which does what I want for the workbook in which the UserForm was created. But the UserForm remains on screen when I click to another workbook. how can I stop this?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name <> "HTFD" And Flight_Deck.Visible = True Then
        Unload Flight_Deck
    End If
    If Sh.Name = "HTFD" And Flight_Deck.Visible = False Then
        Flight_Deck.Show vbModeless
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the UserForm code -

```
Private Sub UserForm_Deactivate()
    Unload.me
End Sub
```

Unloads when losing focus.

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working for me. the userform is still present no matter which workbook i am using although it is only relevant to one.

Comment: Try it out in a fresh workbook. If it works, slowly move the old stuff to the new one and see if it breaks. If it does then you know the offender. If it doesn't then your workbook just went wonky.